# Android, Error indication in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview, android-permissions

My project folder indicates an error as Project name with Red exclamation mark. What does this mean? what should i do to resolve this. THERE IS NO ERROR IN THE CODE.

Comment: Check out your Project Build Target inside your Project Properties and your libraries

Answer (score 1):

The error will typically appear in the "errors" tab. Go to Window->Show View->Error Log and check the errors shown there.

Answer (score 0):

try these

- Project -> Clean
- Project -> Build Project
- Right click on project -> Android Tools -> Fix Android Properties
- Right click on project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path (see if something is wrong there)